# Error message not working as expected in Django

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I am trying to display a message on order creation success or failure. For `messages.success(request, "My message")` it is working as expected. But for `messages.error(request, "My message")` it is not as expected. I read the django messages framework docs, but no use. Can someone tell me why is this happening

*Success Message:* 
[image: Success Message]

*Failed Message:*
[image: Failed Message]
This is supposed to be red alert if I am not wrong.
Here's my html file.

**base.html**

```
<main role="main" class="container"  >
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            messages.success(
                request, "Thank you for ordering! Your items will be delivered soon")
            return redirect(reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, "Your order could not be placed, here are the details:   " + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
        return redirect(reverse('profile-page'))
```

Comment: try printing `{{ message.tags }}` in your `div` . whether it is printing the right css class or not

Comment: It will just display the tag name depending on failure/successful i.e., `'success' for message.success &   'error' for message.error`

Comment: so `alert-error` class is applying ? if you try to make a static div like so : `<div class="alert alert-error">
        red alert worked
      </div>`   does it show you the alert in red ?

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is `alert-error` not working  you can use this after have the import statement of your message :

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}
```

Reference ->

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags

Comment: It didn't work, I am getting the error message as before  `from django.contrib import messages

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}`

Comment: The above method is not overriding error-->danger. Checked printing `message.tags`...it still shows message tag as _error_ meaning it's still `alert-error`

Comment: Sorry the import is different , i have updated in answer also - `from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
`

Comment: Even this didn't work. I tried this even before you suggested, checking the doc you shared, So went back to old way of hardcoding. **module 'django.contrib.messages.constants' has no attribute 'error'** we would get this error if we try importing  `from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages`

Answer (score 0):

@Sowjanya R Bhat

The method you suggest can be hardcoded but I need to know, why isn't it implementing red alert my default. Your suggestion works however

```
<main role="main" class="container"  >
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      {% if message.tags == "error"%}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: you can see what you are showing here is using `alert-danger` class . but what is coming fro your backend is `alert-error` class . i was asking you if `alert-error` works when you hard-code ?

Comment: No this `alert-error` doesn't work . Only `alert-danger` works, not sure why..!!!

Comment: Because bootstrap has built-in `alert-danger` class not `alert-error`

Answer (score 0):

```
In your HTML:

<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
   $('#flash').fadeOut('fast');
   },5000);
</script> 

<div id="flash">
         {% if messages %}
              {% for message in messages %}
                       <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags}} m-0" role="alert">
                              <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
                        </div>
              {% endfor %}
         {% endif %}
 </div>

in django settings.py:

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}

in django views:

    from django.contrib import messages

    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            messages.success(
                request, "Thank you for ordering! Your items will be delivered soon")
            return redirect(reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, "Your order could not be placed, here are the details:   " + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
        return redirect(reverse('profile-page'))
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `messages.warning` instead, it would at least show a color.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `alert-error` is not a bootstrap class.
The according class is named `alert-danger`.

Generally the tags line up nicely between bootstrap and django, this is why your code works. But as you see "error" != "danger".

To fix the issue **replace**

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

with

```
{% if message.tags == "error" %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do in views.py instead of doing:

```
 messages.error(request, "Your order could not be placed, here are the details:   " + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
```

do it:

```
messages.warning(request, "Your order could not be placed, here are the details:   " + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
```